# How to obtain a screen flash effect like screen capture effect?

Tags: swift, macos, animation, screenshot, nsview

Is there any way to obtain a flash screen effect like the one produced when a screenshot is taken, on demand, for a certain NSView? My question is not a duplicate of [flashing screen programatically with Swift (on 'screenshot taken')](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28684549/flashing-screen-programatically-with-swift-on-screenshot-taken) , since I need a solution for osx, not ios and the methods are different.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [flashing screen programatically with Swift (on 'screenshot taken')](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28684549/flashing-screen-programatically-with-swift-on-screenshot-taken)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to achieve this is to create a new UIView that is the same size of the screen, and black in color, add it a subview of your view then animate the alpha to zero( play around with the duration to achieve the desired effect) after completion remove the view from superview.

I have used this technique in many of my projects and it works like a charm. You can play around with the background color of the view to customize the look of the flash.

Answer (score 6):

Something like this might work

```
func showScreenshotEffect() {
    let snapshotView = UIView()
    snapshotView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    view.addSubview(snapshotView)
    // Activate full screen constraints
    let constraints:[NSLayoutConstraint] = [
        snapshotView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor),
        snapshotView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
        snapshotView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor),
        snapshotView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor)
    ]
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate(constraints)
    // White because it's the brightest color
    snapshotView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    // Animate the alpha to 0 to simulate flash
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2, animations: { 
        snapshotView.alpha = 0
    }) { _ in
        // Once animation completed, remove it from view.
        snapshotView.removeFromSuperview()
    }
}
```